# Is EC2 storage really 3 cents per GB?

Tags: amazon-ec2

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Is Amazon blob storage really 3 cents per GB per month? Are there any gotchas?

**EDIT**

Are there additional costs, what if the data is heavily accessed?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? At least make a comment. Peace.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a billing question.

Comment: "Are there additional costs, what if the data is heavily accessed?" Scroll down to "Request Pricing" and "Data Transfer Pricing". AWS pricing is pretty transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - hard drives are right around 3 cents per gig to buy, so 3 cents per gig per month could certainly turn a profit at scale.

Make sure you fully understand the pricing before you dive in (especially if you use the Glacier storage class) - data transfer in and out, API calls, and the storage itself all have cost components.